# bound methods in python

Tags: python, oop

```
>>> class Class:
...     def method(self):
...         print 'I have a self!'
... 
>>> def function():
...     print "I don't..."
... 
>>> instance = Class()
>>> instance.method()
I have a self!
>>> instance.method = function
>>> instance.method()
I don't...
```

Okay the book quotes 'The self parameter (mentioned in the previous section) is, in fact, what distinguishes methods
from functions. Methods (or, more technically, bound methods) have their first parameter
bound to the instance they belong to: you don’t have to supply it. So while you can certainly
bind an attribute to a plain function, it won’t have that special self parameter:'

I am not able to understand what the author is trying to convey here ! I am new to oop in python . Please explain me .

Comment: If this is Python 2, the author is either sloppy, or very out of date. Forgetting to create new-style classes is forgivable in general, but this is one of the key areas where new-style and classic classes are different. Also, while the explanation makes sense to me, I think it would be very muddy to anyone who didn't already know how methods worked. So… I'm not sure how much faith I'd put in this book. What book is it?

Comment: Beginning Python from Novice to Professional , Magnus Lie Hetland

Comment: Well, he definitely knows what he's talking about. And I don't want to be insulting (I'm sure my blog post on [How methods work](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-methods-work.html) would be _far_ more baffling to a novice than this chapter…). But… you might want to find a different book or tutorial to work through classes and methods.

Comment: @abarnert , pls suggest me something for oop , online resources or any good python book .

Comment: I doubt my personal experience would do much good. (I vaguely remember the [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) being pretty good for late-90s language documentation, as long as you were fluent in C, Smalltalk, and Perl…) And in general, StackOverflow is sadly not a good place to get those kinds of recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods only exist on the class; assigning the function to the *instance* attribute as your example does creates an instance attribute containing the *function*, and not a method.

Comment: This is loosely true in Python 3.x (but a lot more of a stretch in 2.x), but I don't think it's very helpful to understanding the difference.

Comment: It's completely true in 2.x; assigning a function to a class attribute, whether before or after instantiation of the class itself from its metaclass, will turn it into a method.

Comment: No, assigning a function to a class attribute doesn't turn it into a method. Look at the class's `__dict__`; it's just a plain old function (in fact, a reference to the _same_ plain old function). The magic happens when you access it via method lookup (or getattr, etc.); when an attribute is found in the class dictionary, its `__get__` method is called and the result returned, and a function's `__get__` method returns a bound or unbound method. (It's loosely true in 3.x because an unbound method just is a function.)

Comment: [Descriptor HowTo Guide](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), [What's New in 2.2](http://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.2.html), [Unifying types and classes](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/), and [PEP 252](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0252/) have all the gory details.

Answer (score 0):

It means that affect of

```
class A:
  def a(self):
    print 'a'
  def b(self, arg):
    print arg
```

can be roughly represented by:

```
def A_a(self):
  print a

def A_b(self, arg):
  print arg

class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = lambda: A_a(self)
    self.b = lambda arg: A_b(self, arg)
```

So `instance.a` is not original function `a` which is written in `class A`, but another function which calls original with additional `self` argument.